# Check both conditions in an if statement even if the first one is false

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have two statements in an if block that both link to a function that will return a bool. Both statements must be true for the code to run but I want them both to be checked even if the first one is false. The relevant code:

```
if (myFunc(one) && myFunc(two)) {
    //execute
}
```

myFunc will execute some code before returning false, but this code is not executed on two if one returns false.

I got this to work, but it feels like a hack:

```
if ((myFunc(one) && myFunc(two)) || (myFunc(two) && myFunc(one))) {
    //execute
}
```

Does anyone have a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: IMO it's bad style if conditions have side effects. The short-circuit behaviour of the logical operators precisely usually does not matter because conditions should not have side effects, hence it should be irrelevant whether they're executed or not. If you want to have side effects, then execute the functions explicitly outside the `if`, not linked by short-circuit operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way:

```
var first = myFunc(one),
    second = myFunc(two);

if (first && second) {
    //execute
}
```

In this case both will be executed first and checked for non false values later.

Comment: +1 If you want to execute two function, then execute two function. It's that simple.

Comment: This works, thanks! Can someone explain how come second is executed if first is false?

Comment: @user Uhm... because it's explicitly executing `myFunc(one)` and `myFunc(two)`...?!

Answer (score 1):

use the & operator

take a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2a4Nc/)

```
function a (){
    console.log(1);
    return true;
}

function b (){
    console.log(2);
    return false;
}

if(b() & a() == true){
console.log('asas');
}
```